# How can I get environment variables from remote Ubuntu server while executing a script on the remote server from local ubuntu system using sshpass?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, ssh

How can I get environment variables from remote Ubuntu server while executing a script on the remote server from local Ubuntu system? I have configured lots of environment variables for vagrant user in different files.

I use the following command to execute the script from local Ubuntu system

```
sshpass -f .passwd ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t vagrant@192.168.1.180 "sh script.sh"
```

The `.passwd` file contains password

While executing this script, configured environment variables not available for script execution. I have sourced profile,  .bash_profile , /etc/profile etc. with this command e.g.

```
sshpass -f .passwd ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t vagrant@192.168.1.180 "source .bash_profile; sh script.sh"
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Note: Environment variables are working fine on a direct ssh session and script too.

Comment: `source .bash_profile; sh script.sh` runs a shell which is not Bash and which runs in a subprocess, which means any variables which are set but not exported will not be visible to the script.  Maybe you want `exec` instead of `sh`? Or maybe the variables you want are not actually defined in the `vagrant` user's `$HOME/.bash_profile` on the remote server?

Comment: Note: Environment variables are working fine on a direct ssh session and script too.

Comment: Your question already states that. Now could you answer the follow-up questions I asked? Are all the variables defined in `.bash_profile` or files which it unconditionally sources? Are the variables exported? Do you want the script to be run by Bash or by `sh`, and if the former, the instance you are already running, or another one?

Comment: All variables are defined in `.bash_profile` and exported in the remote server. Most of my scripts are in bash, so it will be good to find a solution for the bash.

Comment: So does `exec` work for you?

Comment: No, `exec` didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`-i` option with `bash` and `sh` solved the issue. Now I am able to get interactive ssh session in a noninteractive ssh connection.

@marcolz @tripleee Thanks for your help

```
sshpass -f .passwd ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t vagrant@192.168.1.180 "bash -i  script.bash"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `-l` to `sh` it will behave as if it were a login shell and will source your shell resource files, so try:

```
sshpass -f .passwd ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t vagrant@192.168.1.180 "sh -l script.sh"
```

Comment: If `sh` is Bash then yes.

Comment: @tripleee As this is about ubuntu server, it would either be `bash` or `dash` and this should work for both. In the `vagrant` image, it may of course be something else, in theory.

Comment: Oh right, I looked for the option but somehow missed it in the [dash manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dash) ... but it's there alright; it's just missing from the SYNOPSIS section. Thanks.